# Difference in file sizes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My actual XCode project combined file size is around 1 MB. When I do a Build for uploading to the App Store, (i.e. Reveal in Finder for the Products), the file size is around 400 KB. Is that fine?

Also I 2 files under the iPhoneDistribution-iphoneose..one is .dYSm..Which file should I zip and upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hmthur: Yeah the file size is fine because it only considers the XIBs and Resources. All the coding and plist are compressed in the target.

So don't worry about the file size.

It is just fine.

As MacMade as mentioned dSym is Debug Symbols.

So you don't need to compress it and submit it along with the binary.

You can also submit the binary app via Organizer or using Application Loader. So you can use whichever way you find convnient.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

.dSym files are the debug symbols.
Only used for GDB...

Remember an App is binary code. So, it will be less in size that your actual code, with the XCode project and all the support files.

**EDIT**

If you're using XCode 4, you can actually submit your app directly... Just build an archive, from the build menu, and submit it through the XCode organizer.

Comment: so i need to submit the file other than the .dsym ?